# Restricting routes with auth middleware group in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-7

I'm trying to prevent people from accessing the `/dashboard` route unless they're authenticated(logged in). I looked at the laravel docs and here's what I thought I was supposed to do to accomplish this.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function (){
    Route::get('/dashboard', [
        'uses' => 'UserController@getDashboard',
        'as' => 'dashboard'
    ]);
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need to add that extra middleware in the route. Just use the group and you'll be fine. You can see here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-groups

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    // User needs to be authenticated to enter here.
    Route::get('/', function ()    {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });

    Route::get('user/profile', function () {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });
});
```

Comment: I changed my code above to reflect what I currently have, but I can still access `/dashboard`.

Comment: Just to make sure, have you logged once before or authenticated? Have you cleared all your cookies? Try to access it from an incognito window in your browser, just to be sure that you are not logged in. Maybe in your dashboard view do this `if (Auth::check()) { echo "I'm logged in!"; }` or using Blade `@if(Auth::check()) Logged in @endif`

Comment: I had to clear my cookies... rookie mistake, thanks!